# Bad text align hebrew and numeric from mysql to csv file

Tags: php, mysql, encoding, notepad, hebrew

From database i try save to csv file some data. like `"street" : "עין גדי"` and `"house_number" : "7" "street" : "הינתנ"` and `"house_number" : "48"` now it's be look like this `"עין גדי7"` and `"הינתנ48"`

But need that this number writen to right. It's some problem with hebrew and numeric.

how can i fix it?

P.S. If you manually write in notepad, then the number is always ahead

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: put the code you have issue with ;